# Infinite group - unique square root

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is an infinite group, for every $x\in G$, there exists $y\in G$ such that $x=y^2$.

Why would every element in $G$ not have a unique square root in $G$?

Comment: does $(\mathbb C\setminus\{ 0 \}, \cdot)$ have unique square roots?

Comment: On the other hand, $(\Bbb R_{>0},\cdot)$ _does_ have unique roots.

Comment: Finite groups need not have unique square roots either.  Consider $(\mathbb{Q}_8,\cdot)$, the quaternion group.  You have $-1=i^2=j^2=k^2=(-i)^2=(-j)^2=(-k)^2$.  Even more examples can be constructed by taking finite examples and taking the direct product with an infinite group. For example, $(\mathbb{Q}_8,\cdot)\ltimes (\mathbb{Z},+)$

Comment: In the integers under additon $3$ does not have a square root. That contradicts the first sentence in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The nonzero complex numbers under multiplication do not have unique square roots. For instance, $(-2)^2=4=2^2$.